Why the embedding result is different in Spring-AI?
I am working on a project where I need to use text embeddings. I have tried using the Spring-AI embedding in my Java application, but I found that the results are different from those obtained using the Python library sentence-transformers.
Context:

Java/Kotlin Environment: Spring Boot application with Gradle.
Python Environment: Using sentence-transformers library.

Java Code:
import org.springframework.ai.TextEmbedding;

public class EmbeddingExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TextEmbedding embeddingModel = new TextEmbedding("sentence-transformers/all-MiniLM-L6-v2");
        List<Double> embedding = embeddingModel.embed("Hello world");
        System.out.println(embedding.subList(0, 5));
    }
}

Python Code:
from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer

sentences = ["Hello world"]
model = SentenceTransformer('sentence-transformers/all-MiniLM-L6-v2')
embeddings = model.encode(sentences)
print(embeddings[0][:5])

Observations:

The embeddings generated by the Java code using Spring-AI are different from those generated by the Python code using sentence-transformers.
Example output from Java: [-0.19744596, 0.1776652, 0.038569994, 0.14952242, -0.22542042]
Example output from Python: [-0.03447727  0.03102317  0.00673497  0.026109   -0.03936201] 

Questions:

Why are the embeddings different between the two implementations?
Is there a way to ensure that the embeddings are consistent across both Java and Python implementations?
Are there any known issues or differences in the way embeddings are computed in Spring-AI compared to sentence-transformers?

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
Below is the Spring-AI embedding screenshot:

However, using Python library's screenshot is as follow

